# References for the minimal model program

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, birational-geometry, minimal-model-program

What are some references for a beginning graduate student in algebraic geometry to learn about the minimal model program? I'm not thinking about entering this field, but rather I just want to know what it means "to run the MMP".

Related link: [Training towards research on birational geometry/minimal model program](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114050/training-towards-research-on-birational-geometry-minimal-model-program) (the OP had a different goal in mind here)

Comment: Matsuki's book "Introduction to the Mori program" is intended, I think, as a more user-friendly alternative to Koll\'ar--Mori.

Answer (score 6):

Of course it depends mostly on your background. But the first chapter, as well as the first half of the second chapter of Kollár-Mori's "Birational Geometry of Algebraic Varieties" is an incredibly inspiring source in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

A very light introduction is contained in [A first glimpse at the minimal model program](https://goo.gl/qRyLTh). (Also available [here](https://goo.gl/UIIxag).)

I would also second Simone's suggestion: The first two chapters of Kollár-Mori are illuminating.